# Column value of Dataframe as group by clause in Spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a data which looks like table mentioned below

```
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
|User|Shop|Location| Seller|Quantity|         GroupBYClause|
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
|   1| ABC|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|        Shop, location|
|   1| ABC|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|        Shop, location|
|   2| ABC|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|Shop, location, Seller|
|   2| ABC|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|Shop, location, Seller|
|   3| BCD|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|              location|
|   3| BCD|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|              location|
|   3| CDE|    Loc2|Seller3|      10|              location|
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
```

The final output expected is same data with additional column i.e.. Sum(Quantity) which will have the sum of quantity based on the aggregation mentioned by user

for example, user 1 has mentioned GroupBYClause as "shop, location" so independent of seller the sum(quantity) for user 1 is 20

similarly for user 2 the GroupBYClause as "shop, location, Seller" so sum(quantity) will be as same each row that is 10

desired output

```
+------+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+-------------+
|UserId|Shop|location| Seller|Quantity|         GroupBYClause|Sum(Quantity)|
+------+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+-------------+
|     1| ABC|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|        Shop, location|           20|
|     1| ABC|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|        Shop, location|           20|
|     2| ABC|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|Shop, location, Seller|           10|
|     2| ABC|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|Shop, location, Seller|           10|
|     3| BCD|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|              location|           20|
|     3| BCD|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|              location|           20|
|     3| CDE|    Loc2|Seller3|      10|              location|           10|
+------+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+-------------+
```

The challenge I am facing is to use the column value as group by clause in Spark

Please help

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (1, "ABC","Loc1","Seller1", 10, "Shop, location"),
    (1, "ABC","Loc1","Seller2", 10, "Shop, location"),
    (2, "ABC","Loc1","Seller1", 10, "Shop, location, Seller"),
    (2, "ABC","Loc1","Seller2", 10, "Shop, location, Seller"),
    (3, "BCD","Loc1","Seller1", 10, "location"),
    (3, "BCD","Loc1","Seller2", 10, "location"),
    (3, "CDE","Loc2","Seller3", 10, "location")
  )).toDF("UserId","Shop", "Location","Seller", "Quantity", "GroupBYClause")
```

Comment: My first observation is that you're not grouping by anything.  If you were the number of rows coming out would be fewer than the number of rows going in.

Comment: My second observation is that you're using a single column with a comma delimited string to store multiple values where there should only be one value, that's a significant anti-pattern for SQL.  Are you able to store those values in a different table *(With one value per row, rather than one value per cell)*?

Comment: The GroupByClause column is user defined string so that how I get it .. I can split/explode the way I want and need to find the correct sum

Comment: can you add a code line to create you sample dataframe in pyspark?

Comment: I use Scala Spark.. hopefully syntax will not change much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
 df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
      * |User|Shop|Location|Seller |Quantity|GroupBYClause         |
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
      * |1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location        |
      * |1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location        |
      * |2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location, Seller|
      * |2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location,Seller |
      * |3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |location              |
      * |3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |location              |
      * |3   |CDE |Loc2    |Seller3|10      |location              |
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- User: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- Shop: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Location: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Seller: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Quantity: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- GroupBYClause: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### find sum

```scala
    val isShopLocation = Seq("Shop", "location").map(array_contains($"arr", _)).reduce(_ && _)
    val isShopLocationSeller = Seq("Shop", "location", "Seller").map(array_contains($"arr", _)).reduce(_ && _)
    val isLocation = array_contains($"arr", "location")
    df1.withColumn("arr", split($"GroupBYClause", "\\s*,\\s*"))
      .withColumn("arr",
        when(isShopLocationSeller, expr("array(Shop, location, Seller)"))
          .when(isShopLocation, expr("array(Shop, location)"))
          .when(isLocation, expr("array(location)"))
      ).withColumn("sum_quantity",
      sum("Quantity").over(Window.partitionBy("User","arr")))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+
      * |User|Shop|Location|Seller |Quantity|GroupBYClause         |arr                 |sum_quantity|
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+
      * |1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location        |[ABC, Loc1]         |20          |
      * |1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location        |[ABC, Loc1]         |20          |
      * |2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location,Seller |[ABC, Loc1, Seller2]|10          |
      * |3   |CDE |Loc2    |Seller3|10      |location              |[Loc2]              |10          |
      * |2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location, Seller|[ABC, Loc1, Seller1]|10          |
      * |3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |location              |[Loc1]              |20          |
      * |3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |location              |[Loc1]              |20          |
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+
      */
```

### Dynamically defining a partition

```scala
val columns = Seq("Shop", "location", "Seller").flatMap(f => Seq(lit(f), col(f)))
    df1.withColumn("arr", split($"GroupBYClause", "\\s*,\\s*"))
      .withColumn("map1", map(columns: _*))
      .withColumn("arr", expr("TRANSFORM(arr, x -> map1[x])"))
      .withColumn("sum_quantity",
        sum("Quantity").over(Window.partitionBy("User","arr")))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
      * |User|Shop|Location|Seller |Quantity|GroupBYClause         |arr                 |map1                                              |sum_quantity|
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
      * |1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location        |[ABC, Loc1]         |[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller1]|20          |
      * |1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location        |[ABC, Loc1]         |[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller2]|20          |
      * |2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location,Seller |[ABC, Loc1, Seller2]|[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller2]|10          |
      * |3   |CDE |Loc2    |Seller3|10      |location              |[Loc2]              |[Shop -> CDE, location -> Loc2, Seller -> Seller3]|10          |
      * |2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location, Seller|[ABC, Loc1, Seller1]|[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller1]|10          |
      * |3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |location              |[Loc1]              |[Shop -> BCD, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller1]|20          |
      * |3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |location              |[Loc1]              |[Shop -> BCD, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller2]|20          |
      * +----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
      */
```

### Edit-1 (Based on comments)

```scala
// input
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
|User|Shop|Location|Seller |Quantity|GroupBYClause         |
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
|1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location        |
|1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location        |
|2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location, Seller|
|2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location,Seller |
|3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |location,Seller       |
|3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |location              |
|3   |CDE |Loc2    |Seller3|10      |location              |
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+

root
 |-- User: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Shop: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Seller: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- GroupBYClause: string (nullable = true)

// Output
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|User|Shop|Location|Seller |Quantity|GroupBYClause         |arr                 |map1                                              |sum_quantity|
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location        |[ABC, Loc1]         |[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller1]|20          |
|1   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location        |[ABC, Loc1]         |[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller2]|20          |
|2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |Shop, location,Seller |[ABC, Loc1, Seller2]|[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller2]|10          |
|3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |location,Seller       |[Loc1, Seller1]     |[Shop -> BCD, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller1]|10          |
|3   |CDE |Loc2    |Seller3|10      |location              |[Loc2]              |[Shop -> CDE, location -> Loc2, Seller -> Seller3]|10          |
|2   |ABC |Loc1    |Seller1|10      |Shop, location, Seller|[ABC, Loc1, Seller1]|[Shop -> ABC, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller1]|10          |
|3   |BCD |Loc1    |Seller2|10      |location              |[Loc1]              |[Shop -> BCD, location -> Loc1, Seller -> Seller2]|10          |
+----+----+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: this is very good.. but unfortunately I cannot hard code anything as the user may add any combination

Comment: Please check the `Dynamically defining a partition` section, this will work for any combination

Comment: @SomeshwarKale if change fifth row GroupBYClause to "location, Seller", value of "sum_quantity" for sixth row is changed, but have to remain the same.

Comment: @pasha701, sorry not able to understand **"have to remain the same."** can you please post sample example? wanted to try out that

Comment: @SomeshwarKale Expected value "sum_quantity" for sixth row is "20". If change fifth row GroupBYClause = "location, Seller", and use "Dynamically defining a partition" script, then "sum_quantity" for sixth row is "10", please check. I cannot post full example, this will be treated as answer.

Comment: @pasha701, check edit-1 with i/p and o/p. check if this is what you want

Comment: @SomeshwarKale please check last output row from "edit-1", "sum_quantity" value is 10, but 20 is correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The cube function will be helpful here. have a look:

```
#Import and test data
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
tst = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "ABC","Loc1","Seller1", 10, "shop,location"),
    (1, "ABC","Loc1","Seller2", 10, "shop,location"),
    (2, "ABC","Loc1","Seller1", 10, "shop,location,seller"),
    (2, "ABC","Loc1","Seller2", 10, "shop,location,seller"),
    (3, "BCD","Loc1","Seller1", 10, "location"),
    (3, "BCD","Loc1","Seller2", 10, "location"),
    (3, "CDE","Loc2","Seller3", 10, "location")
  ]).toDF("UserId","shop", "location","seller", "quantity", "GroupBYClause")
# split the groupby clause columns to use in udf

tst_in = tst.withColumn("grp_arr",F.split('GroupBYClause',','))
# udf to fetch the values of column in groupby clause
@F.udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def gen_arr(row,group_clause):
    res=[row[x] for x in group_clause]
    return(res)
# The struct can also be constructed for a large column list by list comprehension    
tst_in1 = tst_in.withColumn("grp_coln_arr",gen_arr(F.struct(F.col('shop'),F.col('location'),F.col('seller')),F.col('grp_arr')))
#%% perform a cubed aggregation
   
tst_cub = tst.cube('shop','location','seller').agg(F.sum('quantity').alias('sum_q')).fillna('special_character')
#%% in the cubed aggregation, find the relevant rows
tst_cub1 = tst_cub.withColumn('grp_arr_cub', F.array('shop','location','seller'))
tst_cub2 = tst_cub1.withColumn("grp_arr_cub1",F.array_remove(F.col("grp_arr_cub"),'special_character'))
#%% select the needed quantities using join
tst_res = tst_in1.join(tst_cub2,tst_in1.grp_coln_arr==tst_cub2.grp_arr_cub1,how='left')
```

The results (I have included all the columns for your understanding, make sure to clean them up if you plan to use it)

```
In [99]: tst_res.show()
+------+----+--------+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|UserId|shop|location| seller|quantity|       GroupBYClause|             grp_arr|        grp_coln_arr|             shop|location|           seller|sum_q|         grp_arr_cub|        grp_arr_cub1|
+------+----+--------+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|     2| ABC|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|shop,location,seller|[shop, location, ...|[ABC, Loc1, Seller1]|              ABC|    Loc1|          Seller1|   20|[ABC, Loc1, Seller1]|[ABC, Loc1, Seller1]|
|     2| ABC|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|shop,location,seller|[shop, location, ...|[ABC, Loc1, Seller2]|              ABC|    Loc1|          Seller2|   20|[ABC, Loc1, Seller2]|[ABC, Loc1, Seller2]|
|     3| BCD|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|            location|          [location]|              [Loc1]|special_character|    Loc1|special_character|   60|[special_characte...|              [Loc1]|
|     3| BCD|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|            location|          [location]|              [Loc1]|special_character|    Loc1|special_character|   60|[special_characte...|              [Loc1]|
|     3| CDE|    Loc2|Seller3|      10|            location|          [location]|              [Loc2]|special_character|    Loc2|special_character|   10|[special_characte...|              [Loc2]|
|     1| ABC|    Loc1|Seller1|      10|       shop,location|    [shop, location]|         [ABC, Loc1]|              ABC|    Loc1|special_character|   40|[ABC, Loc1, speci...|         [ABC, Loc1]|
|     1| ABC|    Loc1|Seller2|      10|       shop,location|    [shop, location]|         [ABC, Loc1]|              ABC|    Loc1|special_character|   40|[ABC, Loc1, speci...|         [ABC, Loc1]|
+------+----+--------+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

All distinct "GroupBYClause" can be taken, and Window generated for each, and wrapped with "when(..).otherwise":

```
val distinctGroupBY = df.select("GroupBYClause").distinct().as(Encoders.STRING).collect()

val sumQuantityColumn = distinctGroupBY
  .foldLeft(lit(0))(
    (acc, fieldList) =>
      when($"GroupBYClause" === fieldList,
        sum("Quantity").over(Window.partitionBy("UserId", fieldList.split(",").map(_.trim): _ *)))
        .otherwise(acc)
  )

val result = df.withColumn("Sum(Quantity)", sumQuantityColumn)
```